# skypeforlinux recognises external webcam but gives black screen

Tags: 16.04, drivers, skype, webcam

#### Situation

Ubuntu 16.04, skypeforlinux 8.53.0.85 and 8.58.0.93 (latest to date from the [Skype website](https://www.skype.com/en/get-skype/))

- The external webcam works with Cheese
- The external webcam is **recognized** by Skype as per screenshot below

  - the  vendor and product ID given by `lsusb` show up in the Skype dialogue window (in hexadecimals)
  - the webcam is **on** but the screen is not **activated**: black screen

    [image]

#### Research

This is not  on the official **list of known issues** of Skype for Linux:
https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA34713/faq-and-known-issues-with-skype

A tack of old posts suggests checking whether the **libraries** v4l and gstreamer are installed. They are:

```
ii  libv4l-0:amd64  1.10.0-1  amd64  Collection of video4linux support libraries  
ii  libv4l-dev:amd64  1.10.0-1  amd64  Collection of video4linux support libraries (development files)
ii  libv4l2rds0:amd64  1.10.0-1  amd64  Video4Linux Radio Data System (RDS) decoding library
ii  libv4lconvert0:amd64  1.10.0-1  amd64 Video4linux frame format conversion library
ii  gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0  1.8.3-1ubuntu0.3  amd64  GObject introspection data for the GStreamer Plugins Base library
ii  gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0  1.8.3-1~ubuntu0.1  amd64  GObject introspection data for the GStreamer library
ii  gnome-video-effects  0.4.1-3ubuntu1  all  Collection of GStreamer effects
ii  gstreamer1.0-alsa:amd64  1.8.3-1ubuntu0.3  amd64  GStreamer plugin for ALSA
ii  gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0  3.0.18-1  amd64  Clutter PLugin for GStreamer 1.0
ii  gstreamer1.0-libav:amd64  1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2  amd64  libav plugin for GStreamer
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:amd64  1.8.3-1ubuntu0.3  amd64  GStreamer plugins from the "base" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps  1.8.3-1ubuntu0.3  amd64  GStreamer helper programs from the "base" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:amd64  1.8.3-1ubuntu0.4  amd64  GStreamer plugins from the "good" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly:amd64  1.8.3-1ubuntu0.1  amd64  GStreamer plugins from the "ugly" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly-amr:amd64  1.8.3-1ubuntu0.1  amd64  GStreamer plugins from the "ugly" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio:amd64  1.8.3-1ubuntu0.4  amd64  GStreamer plugin for PulseAudio
ii  gstreamer1.0-tools  1.8.3-1~ubuntu0.1  amd64  Tools for use with GStreamer
ii  gstreamer1.0-x:amd64  1.8.3-1ubuntu0.3  amd64  GStreamer plugins for X11 and Pango
ii  libclutter-gst-3.0-0:amd64  3.0.18-1  amd64  Open GL based interactive canvas library GStreamer elements
ii  libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:amd64  1.8.3-1ubuntu0.3  amd64  GStreamer libraries from the "base" set
ii  libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0:amd64  1.8.3-1ubuntu0.4  amd64  GStreamer development files for libraries from the "good" set
ii  libgstreamer1.0-0:amd64  1.8.3-1~ubuntu0.1  amd64  Core GStreamer libraries and elements
ii  libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer  1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial10  amd64  GStreamer backend for LibreOffice
ii  phonon-backend-gstreamer:amd64  4:4.8.2-0ubuntu2  amd64  Phonon GStreamer 1.0 backend
ii  phonon-backend-gstreamer-common:amd64  4:4.8.2-0ubuntu2  amd64  Phonon GStreamer 1.0.x backend icons
ii  totem  3.18.1-1ubuntu4  amd64  Simple media player for the GNOME desktop based on GStreamer
```

Directing the launch towards the compatibility or conversion libraries either with

`LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l2convert.so /usr/share/skypeforlinux/skypeforlinux`

or

`LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so /usr/share/skypeforlinux/skypeforlinux`

launches Skype but doesn't fix the issue. 
Note that `/usr/bin/skype` is a bash script launching `/usr/share/skypeforlinux/skypeforlinux`, which I have used above as test.

#### Question

Any suggestion on how to have Skype actually send signals through the webcam?

Answer (score 3):

I know of 2 ways to make your webcam work for `skypeforlinux`.

1. Preload one of the Video For Linux compatibility libraries.

   [galiperkin](https://askubuntu.com/a/1226516/756641) mentioned one of them, `v4l2convert.so`; if that doesn't work, you can search for the other one, `v4l1compat.so`, and preload it in your command for starting Skype. For example, if you find that library in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l/`, close Skype and try this command to start it again:

   ```
   LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skypeforlinux
   ```

   If it gives you messages about an incompatible ELF version, you might be loading the 64-bit libraries for a 32-bit Skype, or something like that: search for the other version.
2. Convert exotic webcam output to an accepted format.

   If Skype detects your webcam, but only shows a black rectangle when you open it, then chances are that it just cannot understand the output of the webcam. My own webcam streams in motion jpeg, in a pixel format "yuvj422p" that I never heard of before. Try if `ffplay` can handle it; if it can, `ffmpeg` can too, and that might rescue you.

   First list the available inputs

   ```
    $ v4l2-ctl --list-devices
   ```

   My output reads:

   ```
    BT878 video (Hauppauge (bt878)) (PCI:0000:05:01.0):
        /dev/video0
        /dev/vbi0
    USB Camera (041e:401f) (usb-0000:00:14.0-11.2):
        /dev/video1
   ```

   So I select the second one to test:

   ```
    $ ffplay -hide_banner -f v4l2 -i /dev/video1
   ```

   `-hide_banner` is a convenience parameter, `-f v4l2` chooses the demuxer format, `-i /dev/video1` my webcam.

   If `ffplay` handles your webcam well, you can stop it by typing 'q' on it's video window, and then proceed. Install the loopback driver of Video For Linux; you have to do this only once, but you need sudo rights:

   ```
    $ sudo apt-get update
    $ sudo apt-get install v4l2loopback-dkms
   ```

   This puts slightly more than 100kB extra on your disk: the kernel module `v4l2loopback`. You have to load that into your kernel, another sudo activity:

   ```
    $ sudo modprobe v4l2loopback
   ```

   after which you can immediately detect an extra video input:

   ```
    $ v4l2-ctl --list-devices
   ```

   should now show something like this:

   ```
    BT878 video (Hauppauge (bt878)) (PCI:0000:05:01.0):
        /dev/video0
        /dev/vbi0
    USB Camera (041e:401f) (usb-0000:00:14.0-11.2):
        /dev/video1
    Dummy video device (0x0000) (platform:v4l2loopback-000):
        /dev/video2
   ```

   All that is left to do, is to let `ffmpeg` take the input from your exotic webcam, convert it to a common format like `yuv420p`, and output it through the loopback module to the dummy video device. Sounds complicated, but it 's nothing more than this command: *input format - input - filter - output format - output*

   ```
    $ ffmpeg -hide_banner -f v4l2 -i /dev/video1 -vf format=yuv420p -f v4l2 /dev/video2
   ```

   You can test its working with `ffplay` again:

   ```
    $ ffplay -hide_banner -f v4l2 -i /dev/video2
   ```

   Note that I am taking the input from the new video device, the dummy; video1 would be occupied while `ffmpeg` is reading from it.

   I would like to remark that the ff-combo consumes less than 1% of cpu capacity on my 5-year old. If all goes well, stop `ffplay` by typing 'q' in it's video window, but let `ffmpeg` continue.

   Now go to your Skype, and in the Audio and Video settings select the loopback device named as above: `Dummy video device`. If that works well, all that is left to do is to fine tune, and clean up after you. If it does not, I am as sorry as you are.

   Close off `ffmpeg` when you're ready, by typing `q` in the terminal it is running in. You might give it another try, and give your good old webcam a virtual update by adding filters to ffmpeg; those can go in additional `-vf` parameters, or you can add them before or after the `format=yuv420p`, separated by comma's. Mine needs quite a boost:

   ```
    -vf format=yuv420p,spp=quality=3:mode=hard:qp=5,unsharp=3:3:0.7:5:5:-0.5,hqdn3d,eq=saturation=1.8:gamma=1.4
   ```

   but I am sure you can find your own ffmpeg filters and how to use them. You can try them out with `ffplay` before adding them to your `ffmpeg` commandline

   Now you don't want to read this text and type its commands every time you receive or make a Skype call. I've put mine in `~/.bash_aliases` as follows, under the alias name `videoskype`:

   ```
    alias videoskype="xterm -e /bin/bash -ic 'sudo modprobe v4l2loopback;echo Ready for video call, press q to stop;ffmpeg -hide_banner -f v4l2 -i /dev/video1 -vf format=yuv420p -f v4l2 /dev/video2;sudo modprobe --remove v4l2loopback'&"
   ```

   From now on, the single command `videoforskype`, given in an interactive shell (a normal terminal, or a launcher for something like `bash -ic videoskype`) will open a terminal that asks for your sudo password to load the loopback module, keeps `ffmpeg` running until you stop it, and unloads the loopback module.

   Note that the kernel module loader is quite robust: it handles trying to load an already loaded module gracefully. But if you start `videoskype` again while another instance is running in another terminal, the `ffmpeg` in the new one can not read from its input, and stops, causing the loopback module to be unloaded and the first `ffmpeg` to stop as well.

Success!!

Comment: That's a fantastic solution for a technician, that proves once again that linux should be restricted to remote servers.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and tried a lot of things.
I'm using Ubuntu 19.10(eoan), Skype version 8.59.76.73 and libv4l version is 1.16.7-1.
My solution to this problem is based on [this Ubuntuforums link](https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1937857.html).

1. Remove skype completely from your system with

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge skype*
   ```

   or

   ```
   snap remove skype
   ```
2. Install the libv4l-dev packages

   ```
   sudo apt install libv4l-dev
   ```
3. Find where the lib4l packages downloaded with the following command,

   ```
   find / -iname "*libv4l*" 2>/dev/null
   ```
4. Re-install the latest version of skypeforlinux preview version from [this Skype repository](https://repo.skype.com/deb/pool/main/s/skypeforlinux/).
5. Reboot your system.
6. With the path for libv4l you found, use the following command to run skypeforlinux

   ```
   LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l2convert.so skypeforlinux
   ```

I hope this helps,
I solved my problem with these steps.

Comment: I have also been trying the same Skype version but with version 1.10 of **libv4l**  as supported by **Ubuntu 16.04**. For your suggestion does not work for me, I then suspect that there could be something wrong in the (communication with) that library, whereby Skype does not activate the webcam. Please note that using **Skype pre-release versions** implies particular terms and conditions of use, see https://www.skype.com/en/legal/skype-preview-program-terms/

Comment: are you able to download _dev_ version of the **libv4l** package on your system? Maybe you can also try with that version. Also you can try to download **v4l-utils** with `sudo apt install v4l-utils` .My other suggestion is try to find the correct path for **libv4l** package to use with _*LD_PRELOAD*_ , try other directories from the result of the 3rd step to find correct _v4l2convert.so_ or _v4l2compat.so_ . I also think same way you do about the communication because other applications such as *Zoom* and *guvcview* work well with my external webcam.Thank you to inform me about skype policies

Comment: Yes I had downloaded the dev packages and updated my post; the same now with v4l-utils (`apt show v4l-utils` for description) but to no avail. All libv4l-* are set at version 1.10 for Ubuntu 16. Off-note: rather than `find ...` I often use `locate libv4l`, which is up to date after having run `sudo updatedb`